# Multiple Returns From Radiotray-NG Status Bash Script

Tags: bash, linux-mint-21

I have been writing a bash script for the radiotray-ng applet, fine tuning it through a mountain of trial and error, and I would like it to simply exit the script cleanly after accomplishing this.

It is supposed to return the status of the app, whther its running, playing, or not running.

Here is the code.

```
#!/bin/bash

app="radiotray-ng"

launchrt="/usr/bin/radiotray-ng --play"

playrt=".config/radiotray-ng/rtng-dbus play"

rtstate=$(.config/radiotray-ng/rtng-dbus get_player_state | grep state)

playing=$(.config/radiotray-ng/rtng-dbus get_player_state | grep state | grep playing)

running=$(.config/radiotray-ng/rtng-dbus get_player_state | grep state | grep running)

notrunning=$(.config/radiotray-ng/rtng-dbus get_player_state | grep state | grep Error)

echo $rtstate > /dev/null

if [[ $rtstate = $playing ]]; then 
        echo "RadioTray Is Playing"
else
    if [[ $rtstate = $running ]]; then 
        echo "RadioTray Is Running. Starting Player"
        $playrt    
    else
        if [[ $rtstate = $notrunning ]]; then 
            echo "RadioTray Is Not Running. Launching Player"
            $launchrt    
        fi
    fi
fi
exit 0
```

This is what I get when it's playing:

`RadioTray Is  Playing`

Not playing but still running (launched):

`RadioTray Is Stopped. Starting Player`
At this point it connects to the stream and exits the script cleanly.

And not running at all (exited):
`Error org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.ServiceUnknown: The name com.github.radiotray_ng was not provided by any .service files (4X) RadioTray Is Not Running. Launching Player`

Then it plays. It then hangs until I exit the app, which does so cleanly and without any error messages.

I would like it to return the status of the player (not running, running but not playing, or playing), and exit cleanly. Clearly, this happens now in two of the three possible outcomes. I would like it to perform this every time, if at all possible. I realize it may not be.

The assistance is very appreciated.

Comment: From the findings you postet, I would conclude that the error message comes from the line `/usr/bin/radiotray-ng --play`. You can easily confirm this by running your script with `set -x` turned on. In this case, before thinking of what "return a status" exactly means (this is unclear to me), I would fix this error.

Comment: Hopefully that's a little clearer? Sorry I wasn't specific before. Not sure how to implement the set -x command though, I'm not familiar with it. I appreciate you taking the time to answer, however. Thank you. Did you mean chmod +x, to make it executable?

Comment: Either you put the line `set -x` into your script - tracing will then start from this line -, or you run your script with `bash -x path/to/your/script`, in which case it traces the whole script.

Comment: Where is the variable `$_sdir` set? or do you count on that being empty? (e.g. in `appdir="$_sdir/usr/bin/radiotray-ng"`). Variable expansion will occur within double-quotes, but not single-quotes.

Comment: What is the lone line saying `$playing` doing? Running the content of a variable as a command is not forbidden, but looks fishy - it is a potential source of errors.

Comment: Okay, I will try to trace it in the command line. Had no idear you could even do that. Thanks :)

Comment: `$playing` was the only way I knew of to compare the output of
`pacmd list-sink-inputs | grep "$procbin" | grep "$app" | cut -d '"' -f2` and compare it to the `$appid`

Comment: what's the alternative to `$_sdir`, may I inquire? Found it...probably on this site while I was researching the code. Am I able to declare the directory path without it?

Comment: Just tested it again and realized `$_sdir` is a variable for an old function i'm no longer using. Commented it out

Comment: Commented out every line but 
`set -x /usr/bin/radiotray-ng --play`
and it returned the following in the terminal:
`An instance of radiotray-ng is already running, pid: 67452`

Comment: You might not need to use date. Try `printf`'s `%T` feature.

Comment: Also in your script you're calling `/$HOME/.config/radiotray-ng/rtng-dbus play` twice.  Also it might be better to just `pgrep`: `if pgrep -u "$USER" radiotray-ng &>/dev/null; then`.  Even better, if `radiotray-ng` can accept an option that will make it return an exit status code based on if something is currently playing or not, use that instead.

Comment: This is what `systemd` (and the `systemctl --user` kind of commands / units) is for. Wheel reinventions that parse the output from `ps` etc. are bound to be inefficient, error prone, hard to debug, detached from dependencies on other system components (user session, network etc.), lacking proper lifecycle and log management, status tracking etc. I strongly recommend setting up a `--user` unit for this purpose.

Comment: Thank you both for your responses, its very appreciated. @konsolebox, how would I go about implementing the status code based on whether it's playing, any idear? I think I follow, I just don't know how to go about it

Comment: @AndrejPodzimek, could you enlighten me as to what exactly a user unit is, thank you kindly? Not familiar with that one. Thanks :)

Comment: I thought about getting rid of the the time/date stamp entirely, I just like it and didn't assume it would make a difference as to the state of the app. But I could eliminate it, if you think it would help :)

Comment: I was also wondering...could the ORDER of the functions make a difference? Or maybe nesting them? Perhaps a setup where the script checks to see if the app is running, and if it is, whther it's playing inside of that, then ending with the option to launch if it isn't running after the playing function exits? Just curious.

Comment: @UnaMnt See [Exit Status](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Exit-Status.html). You can't implement the status code of `radiotray-ng`. You can only check it. I don't have that software installed so it's up to you figure out if it has a feature that's triggered by an option that returns an exit status code that depends on whether an instance is already running or not. See my pgrep example. You're supposed to do something similar to that. If `radiotray-ng` doesn't have such feature, you're back to using other methods.

Comment: I think I just about have it. I'm uploading the new code. to the original post.

Comment: @UnaMint Typing “systemd user units” into your favorite search engine may be the best kind of enlightenment out there. The ArchWiki link is really good, but there are lots of other documentation, from `systemd` itself as well as from dozens of distros that use it… My main point was: When it comes to tracking a process’ status / lifecycle / dependencies / logs, a Bash script is not a good solution.

Comment: Thank you, Andrej. I'll prolly give it a shot. Learning new things is fun